# Can't show manual pages for `ls` in Vagrant

Tags: linux, command-line, vagrant, ls, git-bash

That's my first question in here and I'm still a beginner so please bear with me. I'm having a Linux Command Line Basics course on Udacity. I got to the point where I'm asked to open a manual page for the `ls` command by typing `man ls`. But when I enter this command, the terminal says `No manual entry for ls. See 'man 7 documented' for help when manual pages are not available.`. I tried installing `cowsay` and trying to view the manual for it and it worked. But for the manual pages for default commands in the Linux system, it doesn't work. It seems that for some reason the default `ls` commands for the system aren't working but they are working for third-party programs like `cowsay`.

Comment: What OS image are you using? There is probably just a package missing 

Comment: @HorstGutmann By OS image, do you mean the image variant I used for Vagrant? If that's what you mean, that's the link to the image [link](https://app.vagrantup.com/udacity/boxes/ud381) Sorry if I misunderstood your question, I'm still a beginner in the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like that Vagrant box doesn't have the package installed that contains this and other core manpages. You can solve that using the following command:

```
sudo apt install manpages-posix
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I didn't know it was that simple! Looks like I still got a lot of things to learn, haha.